# php error reporting

Tags: php.ini

I have a problem i have a simple lamp server and i want it to display php errors. (apache2) so i go into my php.ini file and `error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT`

The web says this should do the trick but even still i get a blank page when my php file contains errors.

I have made sure i edited the right php.ini since the phpinfo(); says i use /etc/php5/apche2/php.ini i edited that file.

Do you guys have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Error reporting can be set at many levels.  In your php.ini, within apache config, or an htaccess, and also within the PHP code itself.  The php.ini, set a system wide default, and over-ridden, by all the other possible locations.

After you edited the file, did you check the phpinfo() output?  Was the change actually made?

Though there are also rare cases where you have an error so bad, that it actually crashes the apache or php process, these you will usually see in your Apache error log.  These types of failures happen when there is a bug in PHP itself, and your code somehow manages to trigger it.